# How can i make a internal/invisible mod rewrite ONLY for Homepage

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've some different mod rewrites and they are working well. But the most simple one isn't that nice. I just wan't to show a subpage on my Index invisible.

So http://foliodock.com shows http://foliodock.com/blog/index.php?p=4 but still shows just the domain in the browser bar. The current Code is

```
  RewriteRule ^$ blog/index.php?p=4 [L]
```

On the live site it shows foliodock.com/blog/home cause of enabled redirects in my wordpress blog, but if i deactivate them blog/index.php?p=4 shows up like it should.

How do i do this redirect invisible or internal?

I have some additional redirects and also index file in the main root so i can not virtual host to the blog folder or such.

The full redirect is

```
# force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# force not to use www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite Base Url to Blog
RewriteRule ^$ blog/index.php?p=4 [L]

# Skip pier, thumb and blog
RewriteRule ^(pier|timthumb|blog)($|/) $ [L]

# load the index file
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.html [L]
```

Sorry for this stupid problem but i seem to be blind?!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to figure this out for a client.

```
  # make homepage the wordpress index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(|/)$
  Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/ [L]
```

This makes the homepage redirect (invisibly) to the wordpress index page. I'm using this with a Zend project so this condition and rule goes before the rewrite conditions and rules that make zend work.

A word of warning, rewrite rules are not my area of expertise; test this thoroughly before using it on a production server.